# Asp.Net MVC and Web Api with Google Authentication

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to use Google Authentication in a VS2015 solution with 2 Asp.Net projects:

- an MVC App and
- an MVC WebApi.

Logging in with a local username and password works fine. I get back a token after logging in with `api/Token` from the API and can use this on subsequent `httpclient` calls to `api/xxxxxx` methods decorated with [Authorize].

Now I want to add the option to log in with a Google account. I have have managed to get the call to Google working on the front end and get back an `Owin.ExternalLoginInfo` object, but of course calls to the `api/methods` fail with

> unauthorized.

Can someone tell if it's possible to push that `ExternalLoginInfo` back to the API and have it be used for authentication in the backend?